# Help needed in breaking a long equation which contains long sum

Tags: equations

I have an equation which I want to split into two, but it always gives error when I use standard equation breaking techniques, like `\split`, `\gather` etc. The quation is given as

```
\vec{B}^{tra}(\textbf{r})  = \sum^{+\infty}_{n=-\infty}{j^{-n+1}\left[ \frac{k_{+2}c_{n}}{\omega}(\textbf{M}^{1}_{n}(k_{+2}r) +\textbf{N}^{1}_{n}(k_{+2}r))Cos(\theta) 
 -\frac{k_{-2}d_{n}}{\omega}(\textbf{M}^{1}_{n}(k_{-2}r)-\textbf{N}^{1}_{n}(k_{-2}r))sin(\theta)\right]}.
```

I want to write the sine term on second line.

any help will highly appreciated.

FA

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5001) Real quick: By indenting lines of LaTeX code by four spaces -- which may be done smoothly by highlighting the lines in question and clicking on the `{}` "button" in the line above the editing window -- the site will pretty-print the code.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you make the following changes to your code

- To typeset curly braces in TeX/LaTeX, it's necessary to enter them as `\{` and `\}` rather than as `{` and `}`. I've replaced your `{` and `}` terms with curly braces below since you feature them in your example. However, they're not really needed and could thus be omitted entirely.
- Since the curly braces and square brackets will enclose material that's broken across two lines, one can't use `\left` and `\right` to make them "large". I suggest you use the explicit sizing instructions `\biggl` and `\biggr`.
- Don't write `cos` and `sin` but `\cos` and `\sin` to have TeX typeset the materials in an upright roman font rather than in math italics.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % provides the "align*" environment
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\vec{B}^{tra}(\textbf{r}) 
=  \sum^{+\infty}_{n=-\infty}\biggl\{ j^{-n+1}
&\biggl[ \frac{k_{+2}c_{n}}{\omega}
\bigl(\textbf{M}^{1}_{n}(k_{+2}r) +\textbf{N}^{1}_{n}(k_{+2}r)\bigr) \cos(\theta) \\
&\quad {}-\frac{k_{-2}d_{n}}{\omega}
\bigl(\textbf{M}^{1}_{n}(k_{-2}r)-\textbf{N}^{1}_{n}(k_{-2}r)\bigr) \sin(\theta)
\biggr]\biggr\}.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

---

Without the unnecessary curly braces and with the superscript term "tra" typeset in an upright-roman font, the equation looks like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\vec{B}^{\textup{tra}}(\textbf{r}) 
=  \sum^{+\infty}_{n=-\infty} j^{-n+1}
&\biggl[ \frac{k_{+2}c_{n}}{\omega}
\bigl(\textbf{M}^{1}_{n}(k_{+2}r) +\textbf{N}^{1}_{n}(k_{+2}r)\bigr) \cos(\theta) \\
&\quad {}-\frac{k_{-2}d_{n}}{\omega}
\bigl(\textbf{M}^{1}_{n}(k_{-2}r)-\textbf{N}^{1}_{n}(k_{-2}r)\bigr) \sin(\theta) \biggr].
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd remove the braces that serve no purpose.

Comment: @egreg - I've added a second form, without the curly braces. I did think it was important to mention the need to type `\{` and `\}` rather than just `{` and `}` if curly braces are to be typeset.

Answer (score 4):

One possible approach is to use the `split` environment from »[amsmath](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)« (here loaded by »[mathtools](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)«). This makes it necessary to use a manual scale for delimiters by e.g. `\bigg`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}  % loads »amsmath«

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
      \vec{B}^\text{tra}(\textbf{r}) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} j^{-n+1}\bigg[ \frac{k_{+2}c_n}{\omega}(\textbf{M}^1_n(k_{+2}r) +\textbf{N}^1_n(k_{+2}r))\cos(\theta) \\
      {}-\frac{k_{-2}d_n}{\omega}(\textbf{M}^1_n(k_{-2}r)-\textbf{N}^1_n(k_{-2}r))\sin(\theta)\bigg]
    \end{split}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: The "+2" in the numerator of the fraction on the first line seems to have lost its subscript status.

Comment: @Mico: Thanks for that hint. This was not the only place where the underscore for subscripts got lost. Actually I just copied the code from the OP.

Comment: you want to put an empty group `{}` before the minus sign starting the second line to get the correct spacing (binary, not unary).

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Thanks for the hint. Small detail fixed.